# High Availability for Kafka Streams running on OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, high-availability

How do you ensure High Availability for Kafka Streams applications running on OpenShift?

I have a stateful Kafka Streams application consuming from a single-partition topic. Due to complex business needs, the application contains several state stores of significant sizes.

Running a single pod (i.e. application instance) in OpenShift results in large downtimes on redeployments and restarts of the application/pod. The downtime is mainly a result of state restoration from the changelog topics. To mitigate the restoration time, I am running two pods in OpenShift simultaneously and sat `num.standby.replicas = 1`. The use of standby replicas have successfully removed the restoration time. The downside is that I now have an idle pod taking up resources, but that is manageable.

However, I am still experiencing significant downtime due to rebalancing. For instance, if the actively consuming pod is killed, a rebalance is triggered upon restart of the pod. During the rebalance, messages are not processed. Is there a way to reduce the downtime due to rebalancing? Ideally, the idle pod should just take over the message processing instantly if the active pod is killed.

My Streams config:

```kotlin
val props = Properties()
    props["bootstrap.servers"] = "my-brokers.com"
    props[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "my-application-id"
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = Serdes.String()::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = SpecificAvroSerde::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG] =
        LogAndContinueExceptionHandler::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG] = -1
    props[StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG] = 1
    props[AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = "my-schema.registry.com"
```

Comment: You can only have one active pod be a consumer since you only have one partition. If you want higher availability, increase your standby replicas. And, rebalancing must happen, but have you looked into the cooperative rebalancing setting?

Comment: Yes, I tried to look into the cooperative rebalancing, but frankly I didn’t understand much :/ Do you have any resources that shows examples on how it works and how to configure the streams application?

Comment: According to the blog, if you're running Streams version 2.5 or higher, it is the default behavior https://www.confluent.io/blog/cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka-streams-consumer-ksqldb/ So, which are you using? But still, that doesn't matter because rebalancing only happens on restarts or multiple instances, whereas you're locked at one

Comment: I'm using Kafka 3.3.1

Comment: That's broker version? I meant your app `kafka-streams` dependency version?

Comment: The `kafka-streams` version is 3.3.1.

Comment: In that case, I'm not really sure about the rebalancing. But without a standby, it obviously will need to... And you cannot scale beyond one active instance, for that  input topic, as mentioned.

Comment: Would it be possible to ensure High Availability if the topic consisted of more than one partition?

Comment: Yes. With the tradeoff that your data would no longer be absolutely ordered, as data will be only be ordered within each individual partition

Comment: But is it possible to ensure no consumption downtime for all partitions in a topic? To me, it seems like we are bound to have downtime due to rebalancing :/

Comment: Yes. That's what replication-factor is for, with unclean.leader.election=false

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat viable solution!

In OpenShift, I set `replicas=3`, meaning 3 instances of the application is spun up. I also set `initialDelaySecond = 180` for both the `health` and `liveness` endpoint. This gives the new standby replicas time to restore their state before the original pods/predecessors are termintated.

For the Kafka stream setup, I used

```kotlin
val props = Properties()
    props["bootstrap.servers"] = "bootstrap.server"
    props[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "application-id"
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = Serdes.String()::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = SpecificAvroSerde::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG] =
        LogAndContinueExceptionHandler::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG] = -1
    props[StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG] = 2
    props[AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = "schema.registry"
    props[ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG] = 10000
```

with the following application termination

```kotlin
val kafkaCloseOptions = CloseOptions().leaveGroup(true)
stream.close(kafkaCloseOptions)
```

This application termination will result in unncessary rebalances, but since rebalancing in our case only took milliseconds to perform, it was worth it.